# surjective homomorphism between free abelian groups and first isomorphism theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, free-abelian-group, module-isomorphism

So i recently started studying homology groups and whenever i stumbled upon its general idea or motivation, i came across computations such as

$$ \langle a,b,c\rangle / \langle c \rangle = \langle a,b \rangle $$

where each $\langle \cdot \rangle$ is a free abelian group.

Unfortunately, my algebra background isn't solid but i learned that the reason for the given equation (and others) is the first isomorphism theorem. In order to show that the quotient group $\langle a,b,c\rangle$ and $\langle a,b\rangle$ are isomorphic, i just need to find a surjective homomorphism $$\varphi: \langle a,b,c\rangle \to \langle a,b\rangle$$ whose kernel $\ker \varphi$ is $\ker \varphi = \langle c\rangle$.

My question is rather simple: How exactly does such surjective homomorphism look like?

We have $$\langle a,b,c\rangle = \{m_1a+m_2b+m_3c \mid m_1,m_2,m_3 \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$ and $$\langle a,b \rangle = \{n_1a+n_2b \mid n_1,n_2 \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

I was thinking of something like \begin{align*} \phi \left((m_1a+m_2b)+m_3\right) &= \phi(m_1a+m_2b)+\phi(m_3c)\\ &= \phi(m_1a)+\phi(m_2b) + \phi(m_3c) \\ &= m_1\phi(a) + m_2\phi(b) + m_3\phi(c) \\ &= m_1 + m_2\end{align*}

thus the homomorphism which sends $a \mapsto 1, b \mapsto 1$ and $c \mapsto 0$ for which we have $\ker \phi = \langle c \rangle$.

Would this be a legitimate approach? Thanks for any advise!

Comment: I think what you did works fine.

Comment: @panoulis: No, it isn't....

Comment: What you did does not quite work the way you want, because (i) you are not mapping to the free group in two generators; and (ii) the kernel is **larger** than $\langle c\rangle$. For example, $a-b$ maps to the kernel. In fact, the kernel is $\langle a-b,c\rangle$. You are not mapping to $\langle a,b\rangle$, you are mapping to $\mathbb{Z}$. So you should instead have the image be in $\langle a,b\rangle$.

Comment: $a\mapsto a$, $b\mapsto b$, $c\mapsto 0$, if that is what you mean.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thank you! would the homomorphism that sends $a \mapsto a, b \mapsto b$ and $c \mapsto 0$ do the job?

Comment: @Zest: That would work, yes.

Comment: perfect! thanks for your help.